# How can I recover (or reset) the GPG keys of *.debian.org?

Tags: apt, gpg

So I guess I deleted or corrupted the gpg keys I had for *.debian.org, which makes `apt-get update` yield

```
Ign http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie InRelease
Réception de : 1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63,1 kB]
Réception de : 2 http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease [166 kB]
Réception de : 3 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2 434 B]
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Réception de : 4 http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [145 kB]
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Err http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease

Réception de : 5 http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [27,8 kB]
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie Release
Ign http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie Release
Réception de : 6 http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/contrib amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [25,3 kB]
Ign http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Sources/DiffIndex
Ign http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Atteint http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
Atteint http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/contrib Translation-en
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Translation-fr
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-fr_FR
Ign http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-fr
Atteint http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-en
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Sources
Atteint http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie/main Translation-fr_FR
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/contrib Translation-fr_FR
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/contrib Translation-fr
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-fr_FR
Ign http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports/main Translation-fr
430 ko réceptionnés en 2s (175 ko/s)
Lecture des listes de paquets…
W: Erreur de GPG : http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease : Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible : NO_PUBKEY (SOME hexadecimals) NO_PUBKEY (SOME hexadecimals)
W: Erreur de GPG : http://ftp.debian.org jessie-backports InRelease : Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible : NO_PUBKEY (SOME hexadecimals) NO_PUBKEY (SOME hexadecimals)
W: Une erreur s'est produite lors du contrôle de la signature. Le dépôt n'est pas mis à jour et les fichiers d'index précédents seront utilisés. Erreur de GPG : http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease : Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible : NO_PUBKEY (SOME hexadecimals) NO_PUBKEY (SOME hexadecimals)

W: Erreur de GPG : http://ftp.fr.debian.org jessie Release : Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible : NO_PUBKEY (SOME hexadecimals) NO_PUBKEY (SOME hexadecimals) NO_PUBKEY (SOME hexadecimals)
W: Impossible de récupérer http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie-updates/InRelease  

W: Le téléchargement de quelques fichiers d'index a échoué, ils ont été ignorés, ou les anciens ont été utilisés à la place.
```

"Les signatures suivantes n'ont pas pu être vérifiées car la clé publique n'est pas disponible" roughly translates as "following signatures couldn't be checked because public key isn't available".

How can I revert those mistakes ?

Update : I did

```
# wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/debian-archive-keyring/debian-archive-keyring_2017.5~deb8u1_all.deb
# dpkg -i debian-archive-keyring_2017.5~deb8u1_all.deb
```

But nothing changed. I suspect what caused the whole thing is

```
# curl -s https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg | apt-key remove
```

to remove the gpg key I just added few minutes before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already reinstalled the `debian-archive-keyring` package, the actual key files should now be in place. But the reinstallation failed to re-add the keys as trusted, possibly because of certain conditions in the `postinst` script in the package that seem to be related to migration from Debian squeeze to jessie.

You'll probably need to do this (or something very similar):

```
# cd /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d
# for i in *.gpg ; do apt-key add $i; done
```

If the actual keys are still missing, the brute-force way is to extract the package manually:

```
mkdir /tmp/workdir
cd /tmp/workdir
ar x /some/where/debian-archive-keyring_2017.5~deb8u1_all.deb
tar xvf data.tar.xz
```

Now you should definitely have the key files in directory `/tmp/workdir/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`. Copy them into place and then use the `apt-key add` command as suggested above.

Comment: I had some `.gpg~` keys in the folder. Dumbly enough, I told myself if i removed them, I could reset them with `dpkg -i debian-archive....` and then add them with `apt-key`, like you mentionned. But now, the keys aren't reinstalled with `dpkg -i debian-archive-keyring_2017.5~deb8u1_all.deb`. (Ie, `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` is empty). Any idea on how to correct ?

Comment: It isn't too difficult to extract the package manually without using `dpkg` at all. I edited that procedure into my answer too. By the way, check with `df` if your disk is full: that might explain why installing with `dpkg -i` didn't work.

Comment: after adding the keys in the package (`debian-keyring.gpg  debian-maintainers.gpg  debian-nonupload.gpg  debian-role-keys.gpg`), apt update still produces the same output. (as a sidenote, DF tells me my disk are up to 6% full)

Comment: After my suggested procedure, the keys you want are in the `/tmp/workdir/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` directory and named like `debian-archive-*.gpg`. You got something else: probably the public keys used in signing security announcements and the like.

Comment: Ok, I found them (I must have chose the wrong package before, because the etc/ folder didn't exist in it.). I assume I should only use the debian-archive-jessie*.gpg one ?

Comment: Adding the keys for stretch won't hurt anything and will be necessary if you ever plan to update from jessie to stretch.

Comment: Well, i still have got some "unknown keys ...", but for the most part it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Download [`debian-archive-keyring`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/debian-archive-keyring) (this links to the Jessie version), and install it manually (as root):

```
dpkg -i debian-archive-keyring_2017.5~deb8u1_all.deb
```

This will restore the keys in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d` and you should be able to run `apt` again.

Comment: This hasn't changed anything. I attempted to remove some old gpg keys through `curl -s https://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg | apt-key remove`. Any ideas ?